# How to get rid of @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") while casting Objects in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, casting

Netbeans IDE is suggesting to add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") before few lines in the code. I can't understand why. Someone please suggest where I am going wrong  ?

```
private List<Object> processNames() {

    List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> addedNames = new ArrayList<>();;
    List<String> droppedNames = new ArrayList<>();;
    Map<String, String> changedNames = new LinkedHashMap<>();


 //I skipped code that adds values into above lists and Map
    values.add(addedNames) ;
    values.add(droppedNames) ;
    values.add(changedNames) ;

    return values:
```

}

```
  private void applyChanges() {
    List<Object> values = processNames();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")// Suggested by IDE
            List<String> AddedNames = (List<String>) values.get(0);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> droppedNames = (List<String>) values.get(1);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, String> changedNames = (Map<String, String>) values.get(2); 

    }
```

Comment: Put it once annotating the method.

Answer (score 3):

Your IDE is suggesting it because there is no way for it to confirm that the data you are trying to retrieve is of the type that you are casting it to (unchecked type cast). This annotation does not necessarily mean an `Exception` is going to be thrown, it is just for casting; in other words, it is used for suppressing the compiler warnings for the annotated element.

In terms of getting rid of that annotation, I would suggest creating your own custom `Object`. (Seems more appropriate to maintain 1 `List<CustomObject>` of data as opposed to 4 separate).